# Put together Shapefiles with data for individual years into Multiple Year Space-Time Cube

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, census, hot-spot, space-time-cube

[image]

I have 16 shapefiles (listed above).  Each shapefile contains county-level data on mortality rates for years 1999 to 2015, respectively.  I organized the mortality rate data in Excel.  I joined the Excel data to an empty US_county_polygon data map by joining FIPS (commonly used to identify counties in census data).

I am creating a space time cube in ArcMap. Space time cubes require a SINGLE input file with data for all years. I have MULTIPLE input files.

I cannot match my **multiple** files to the same US_County_polygon reference shapefile.  Perhaps, because I join them using FIPS.  Each time I join a new single-year shapefile using FIPS to the master US_County_polygon shapefile, it writes over the prior file.

How can I amalgamate the data to create a space time cube?

Comment: Why are you not Merging them

Comment: Good question!  So remember it's mortality-rate data which I am comparing in each US_county over each year.  When I merge my multiple, year-specific, files into one file, arcmap creates a new mortality-rate data column with a numbered prefix for each new mortality-rate column of data.  For instance mortality rate data for US_County_1999 gets the prefix US_County_1999_mortality and is merged next to US_County_2000_mortality.  Obviously, the space time cube requires that the variable to be measured (mortality rate) is entered under a single name, rather than multiple names.

Comment: Use field mapping with merge tool